# cocos2d 3.0 how to handle touch swallowing with priority

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

Since CCTargetedTouchDelegate has been removed since cocos2d 3.0, I would like to know how can i handle touch swallowing stuff?

I have a small sprite on top of a canvas node(layer in 2.x) and need to set the priority of the sprite higher than the canvas. When a user touches within the sprites bounding box, the touch is swallowed, otherwise the canvas will respond to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cocos2d 3.0 touches are handled in reverse z-order order. This means that if your sprite is rendered on top of the canvas node it should already receive touch notification first, and has a chance to swallow it.

However, to receive and swallow the touch by the sprite you should follow these steps:

1. Create a separate class for your sprite and inherit it from
   `CCSprite`.
2. Set `self.userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` in the `init` method
   if this class.
3. Add **empty** `touchBegan:` method.

This will swallow the touch, because without calling `[super touchBegan:...]` in the `touchBegan:` method, you won't pass it to the underlying nodes.

The default implementation of `CCSprite` (and all the way up to `CCNode`) calls the `[super touchBegan:...]`, this is why you need to create a subclass and override this behaviour.

In case you do need to pass touches to underlying nodes in some cases, you can write something like this:

```
-(void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (_passToUnderlyingNode == YES)
    {
        //passed to canvas node
        [super touchBegan:touch withEvent:event];     
    }
    else
    {
        //swallowed
    }
}
```

Comment: so the only thing [super touchBegan] does is to pass down the touch?

Comment: Yes. Here is Cocos2D documentation for `CCResponder`, which is a base class for `CCNode` http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCResponder.html

Comment: what about when I need to handle touches outside the sprite? How can I receive such touches

Comment: Just add the touchBegan: and set the self.userInteractionEnabled to YES for the scene itself.

Comment: no, i mean i need to handle it in the sprite class for some reason

Comment: You can override the `hitTestWithWorldPos:` method of `CCNode`, but I'd suggested you to handle touches in the scene and simply pass them to your sprite . This will just make code more obvious and readable. Otherwise after few months you will be wondering how things work. But this is only my opinion.